# Unexpected white fill from expanded path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I drew a bended line (?) using pen tool and use it as a png file.  So I copy paste the line in Photoshop and try to save as a PNG, BUT I'm seeing this white line...

think this has sth to do with expanding the path, so I expanded the path by going to object --> then path, but it still didn't work..! Still seeing the white thing.

Would very much appreciate your help.

[image]

I don't think I applied anything to fill

[image]

Comment: Do you have the shape fill applied to the path by any chance? That could be a reason.

Comment: You have a white fill applied to something, but without seeing the actual paths and/or your layers it's hard to see whats going on.

Comment: @AdrianJasonNizzetto  don't think i applied fill to the path - attached screenshots

Answer (score 3):

The question mark shown for the fill means you have *multiple* fills selected. If you had no fill it would show the same white with a red line through as your stroke is showing.

[image]

You have a superfluous path left in the middle of your shape (I assume left over from however you expanded the path in the first place). This is what has a white fill. You don't need the path so select it with the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) and delete it.

[image]